# Lua Create local function with table not working

Tags: lua

Hey I have table with keys thad represent the function names when i do this it works

```
local example = {LocalFunction = true}
for fnName, _ in pairs(example) do
    _G[fnName] = function()
        print('This works')
    end     
end 
LocalFunction() -- output This Works
```

But when I want it to be local it doesnt work is there any solution ?

```
local example = {LocalFunction = true}

for fnName, _ in pairs(example) do
    local fnName = function()
        print('This works')
    end     
end 
LocalFunction() -- output nil value
```

Thanks in advance Neo

Comment: You can't create local variables at run time. They are stored in VM registers, not in a table. The closest thing is to use a local environment by setting `_ENV` to a custom table, perhaps inheriting from the original environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As lhf said, you can not add local variables at runtime. You can modify them using [debug.setlocal](https://www.lua.org/pil/23.1.1.html), but they need to be defined within the scope.

A proper workaround would be a local table containing the functions, e.g.:

```lua
local example = {LocalFunction = true}

local localFunctions = { }
for fnName, _ in pairs(example) do
    localFunctions[fnName] = function()
        print('This works')
    end     
end 
localFunctions.LocalFunction() -- output This Works
```

If you can not use a table for some reason, you could modify the [environment](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html) in a temporary way.
(http://lua-users.org/wiki/EnvironmentsTutorial)

```lua
-- create environment, use a metatable to use a protected copy of the old environment
local oldEnv = _ENV
local _ENV = setmetatable({}, {__index = _ENV})

local example = {LocalFunction = true}
for fnName, _ in pairs(example) do
    _ENV[fnName] = function()
        print('This works')
    end     
end 
LocalFunction() -- output This Works

-- restore environment, if required
_ENV = oldEnv

LocalFunction() -- no longer works
```